# VxWorks: PART_ID of system memory partition

Tags: c, memory, malloc, vxworks

Functions like `memPartInfoGet()` require `PART_ID`, in the manual it states that `malloc()` uses free lists of system memory partition. Is there a way to get `struct mem_part* PART_ID` that identifies with the system partition? To be able to use those functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`memSysPartId` is what I was looking for.